# Check if user completed all tests

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have multiple tests. Each user can take all these tests more than 1 time. But he has to complete all the tests, Before taking them again.

So if there are 5 tests, The user has to finish these 5 tests to be able to take them again later.

Tests table:

```
_________________
| id |   test   |
|____|__________|
|  1 |   test1  |
|____|__________|
```

Questions table:

```
____________________________
| id | question |  test_id |
|____|__________|__________|
|  1 |    q1    |     1    |
|____|__________|__________|
```

Answers table:

```
_______________________________
| id |  answer  |  question_id |
|____|__________|______________|
|  1 |    a1    |       1      |
|____|__________|______________|
```

I would then create a table to save user's answers:

User's answers table:

```
________________________________________________________
| id |  user_id  |  test_id  |  question_id | answer_id |
|____|___________|___________|______________|___________|
|  1 |      1    |     1     |       1      |     1     |
|____|___________|___________|______________|___________|
```

And to check if the user completed the test, I would count the user's answers for the test with `id = x`  from table `user_answers` and compare them to the number of questions for this test from table `questions`. If the 2 numbers match, Then it's completed. If not, Then it's not completed.

But the issue is if the user answered all the questions for a test and then new questions were added to that test, It would be considered as not completed.

So how to check if the user answers all the test questions without considering the newly added questions nor deleted ones?

**Please note: Each question is submitted individually, So the user doesn't have to submit all the questions at 1 time, Thus I can't depend on the date when the user answers a question**

Comment: You could maybe depend on the date when the system noticed that the user had completed all the currently-existing questions. Store that in a table which links the user to the test. Then compare it with the date any given question was added to the test.

Comment: Or, consider versioning the tests and even the questions themselves (if the questions can be modified after creation). So for each question associated with a test you'd also store what version of the test it is included with. And you'd have a table storing the version history of the test and the date each version was created. Then when the user starts the test, you'd store which version the test was at that moment. You can then use that to work out whether they had completed all the questions which were associated with the test at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new table which saves question_id user_id, and when a user answers a question you mark that question for him as not new

```
| question_id |  user_id | new_question
```

To know if all answers are answered, you exclude all questions that are marked as new

Answer (score 0):

add new table

```
user_tests [id, test_id, user_id, question_count, answer_count]
```

You can get count of uncompleted tests :

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_tests 
WHERE question_count != answer_count 
AND user_id = 11
```